# Search backwards word in line

Tags: regex, string, tcl

I need to search for a long word and then get the numbers before.

I will explain: if I have this line:

```
208.86 Mhz  cr_st|altpll_component|clk[0]
```

I need to find the string `cr_st|altpll_component|clk[0]`,
then I need to set some variable with the string `208.86 Mhz`.

I tried to do so with search for the string

```
set timing_file [open $link/temp_st.sta.rpt]
while {[gets $timing_file line] != -1} {
 incr line_num
 if {[regexp {cr_st|altpll_component|clk[0]\s+(.*)} $line all FEC_CLK]} {
    puts $line_num
 }
}
close $timing_file
```

Comment: What is your question? What do you expect to happen and what happens instead?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use `scan` to get the value and the unit. Make sure to test that you get both.

```
if {[regexp {cr_st|altpll_component|clk[0]\s+(.*)} $line all FEC_CLK]} {
    # new code
    if {[scan $line {%f %s} value unit] == 2} {
        set some_variable "$value $unit"
    }
    # end new code
    puts $line_num
}
```

Documentation:
[scan](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/scan.htm)

Answer (score 0):

All you need is to use a specific pattern to extract a number and a word before a certain "hard-coded" string.

Use a capturing group around the pattern part you need to extract and use

```
set a {208.86 Mhz  cr_st|altpll_component|clk[0]}
regexp {(\d[\d.]*\s*\w+)\s+cr_st\|altpll_component\|clk\[0]} $a - result
puts $result
```

See the [Tcl demo](http://ideone.com/aoFh5B). If you need to make the number matching part more precise, you may use `\d+(?:\.\d+)?`. See the explanation below:

- `(\d[\d.]*\s*\w+)` - Capture Group 1:

  - `\d[\d.]*` - a digit (`\d`) followed with 0+ digits or dots (as an alternative, you may use `\d+(?:\.\d+)?`: 1+ digits (`\d+`) followed with 1 or 0 occurrences (i.e. optional) of a dot and 1+ digits)
  - `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
  - `\w+` - 1 or more word chars (letters/digits/`_`)
- `\s+` - 1+ whitespace symbols
- `cr_st\|altpll_component\|clk\[0]` - a literal string `cr_st|altpll_component|clk[0]` (note the `|` and `[` must be escaped to be treated as literal chars, otherwise they are parsed as regex operators)

Note the `- result` in the `regexp` line: `-` stands for a whole match (and since we are not interested, `-` is fine) and `result` will hold the value of the first (and only) capturing group.